# jQuery simple tooltip not showing even though event triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

first of, this is what I got:

```
        $('div.pickup').load('/pages/pickup.php?pickup=' + pickup, function() {

            $('div.pickup').fadeIn(300);

            var box = $('#tooltip');
            var trigger = $('.tip');

            trigger.hover(function(e) { 
                alert('Showing tooltip with text: ' + $(this).attr('title'));
                box.text($(this).attr('title'));
                box.css({
                    'top': (e.pageY - 10) + 'px',
                    'left': (e.pageX + 20) + 'px'
                }).fadeIn(300);
            }, function() {
                box.hide();
            });

            trigger.mousemove(function(e) {
                box.css({
                    'top': (e.pageY - 10) + 'px',
                    'left': (e.pageX + 20) + 'px'
                });
            });

        });
```

A table header contains the *'trigger class'* named `.tip`. Every element with that class should initiate the tooltip when hovered. The **th** containing the `.tip`-class looks like this:

`<th class="type red b_l b_b tip" title="test">T</th>`

I expected the tooltip to show up near the mouse cursor when hovering the `<th>` element containing `class="tip"`, the **hover event fired** but all I got was the dialogue box from the **alert()** call.

The `#tooltip` div element is just one line in the *PHP*-file; `<div id="tooltip"></div>`

CSS:

```
#tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px #000000;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the tooltip aint hidden behind another element (ie. the table containing the ), `#tooltip` is the only element with a `z-index` manually set. I even tried `z-index: 999`.

What am I doing wrong?

- Tested in latest IE and FF versions

Comment: Where is your `#tooltip` element located in your HTML? Although it looks like you're setting the `top` and `left` properly, if it's not a child of `body`, it might not be positioned `absolute`ly correctly

Comment: It is located within the PHP-file's `<body></body>` elements; I put it at the very bottom right above the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Okay good, otherwise it would need to have all static ancestors. But you don't have to worry about that. Anyways, it works here for me: http://jsfiddle.net/AEmk9/ (I changed a few things)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I've to put an answer since I can't comment, can you locate the tool tip in the developer tools in FF ? 
It should highlight for you the location of the tool tip, and you should be able to check & set it's visibility via the JS console

Comment: I have never worked with these tools before but they look quite promising, thank you for the hint.

Comment: Eh no problem, they are quite usefull, they allow to test stuff live, like changing CSS, JS, or even HTML, for people like me who work on ASP .NET it's really helpful

Comment: @phew btw, do you mind upvoting my answer ? I need the rep to be able to comment, sorry to beg for it, but without it I can't add comments for trivial matters like those

Comment: Sorry but I doubt that its in the communities interest to upvote on request. You will reach the rep score to be able to comment on answers quickly, it doesn't take that much.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I simply removed the `alert()` call and out of a sudden it works. I'm not sure how `alert()` affects the code following on it, but it seems to interrupt it at some point.

Anyways, removing the `alert()` which was for debug purposes fixed the problem and the tooptip shows fine in both, *FF* and *IE*.

Though, thank you for your suggestions!